# Pegar somente o nome e sobrenome do usuário

Tags: php

Caros colegas.

Como eu poderia pegar o nome e o sobrenome de um usuário? Costumo usar da seguinte forma:

```
$nomeUsuario = 'Francisco de Assis';
list($nome,$sobrenome) = explode(' ',$nomeUsuario);
```

Porém dessa forma eu pegaria **Francisco de** e na verdade gostaria de pegar Francisco Assis.

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como eu faria isso?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Experimenta assim

```
$partes = explode(' ', $nomeUsuario);
$primeiroNome = array_shift($partes);
$ultimoNome = array_pop($partes);
```

- [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) - remove e retorna o primeiro valor do array.
- [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) - remove e retorna o último valor do array.

Comment: Obrigado Maicon. Funcionou!!